# graphql-compose: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTypeName' of undefined

Tags: graphql, graphql-compose

I am trying out `graphql-compose` library and following their [Getting started Github page](https://github.com/graphql-compose/graphql-compose), I build a very simple example.

Here is my code:

```
    import { schemaComposer } from "graphql-compose";

    export const UserTC = schemaComposer.createObjectTC({
      name: "UserTC",
      fields: {
        name: "String",
        surname: "String"
      }
    });

    UserTC.addResolver({
      kind: "query",
      name: "userFind",
      resolve: async () => {
       return []; // empty array
      }
    });

    schemaComposer.Query.addFields({
      userFind: UserTC.getResolver("userFind")
    });

    export const schema = schemaComposer.buildSchema()
```

I am getting the below error when I pass the returned schema object into
  my Apollo server:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTypeName' of undefined`

The error stack point to the last line of my code. I cannot figure out 
  what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for your help.

I can possible not see what error I am doind

Comment: I wouldn't wrap your declarations with quotes. name: "String" probably should real name: String

Comment: That is because it is a json object I am passing to the `createObjectTC`

Comment: I removed the quotes but I'm still getting the same error. I even started a new clean project with the bare minimum...same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add "type" to resolver:

```
UserTC.addResolver({
  kind: "query",
  name: "userFind",
  type: UserTC,
  resolve: async () => {
   return []; // empty array
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was my mistake. I actually fixed it yesterday already